# rdebug-ide is exploading is my rdebug-ide incantation wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jetbrains-ide, rubymine

Remote debugging in rubymine and I’m getting this error…

```
dev$ rdebug-ide --host 0.0.0.0 --port 1234 --dispatcher-port 26162 -- bin/rails s
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.7.2, ruby-debug-base19x 0.11.32, file filtering is not supported) listens on 0.0.0.0:1234
Uncaught exception: cannot load such file -- /home/fonso/dev/bin/rails   <------ WHY THIS GO BOOM???
    /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/bin/rdebug-ide:23:in `load'
    /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/bin/rdebug-ide:23:in `<main>’
```

Given this error, I suspect my rdebug line is wrong...that "bin/rails s” part.

I’m running rbenv on my server so when I run my app their I have to do it this way…

```
dev$rails s -p 4000 -b 0.0.0.0
```

How do I modify this rdebug line so I do not exit out with this error?

FYI: I'm following instructions from the jetbrains site... https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/remote-debugging-with-product.html#configure_remote_interpreter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found:

So this line in the original tutorial is incorrect

```
rdebug-ide --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4000 --dispatcher-port 26162 -- $COMMAND$
```

In that it fails to explain what exactly you should replace, or for that matter that you even have to replace, $COMMAND$ with. Upon many teeth grinding machinations and running permutations of my own I discovered a working solution.

```
rdebug-ide --port 1236 --dispatcher-port 26166 --host 0.0.0.0 -- script/rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```